# Rename filename.JPG to filename .jpg recursively

Tags: scripting

Rename filename.JPG to filename .jpg recursively

I want all the files with .JPG extension to be changed as .jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I too find it now thanks anyways

```
rename 's/\.([^.]*$)/.\L$1/' *.JPG
```

This will fix my issue

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but this will work recursively

```
find . -name '*.JPG' -exec 'sh' '-c' 'mv {} $(sed "s/\.JPG$/\.jpg/" <<< {})' ';'
```

Comment: I need to change the .bmp to .jpg how can I do that...I get this error in ur script sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: @Danny It is working for me, on both `bash` and `zsh`. What are you using? Judging by the error, try: `find . -name '*.JPG' -exec 'sh' '-c' 'mv {} $(echo {} | sed "s/\.JPG$/\.jpg/")' ';'`. For the `.bmp` to `.jpg`, is it just the extension or do you want to convert the file?

Comment: this worked perfectly....I changed the .JPG to .bmp that solves my issue thanks a ton